# Drupal 8 Index pdf files in search

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Does anyone know of a way to include pdf documents in the search for drupal 8?

I can't find anything to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Including PDF documents in a search, requires you to index those PDF documents. This might prove to be a difficult task on Drupal 8, since there are not a lot of stable solutions.

That being said, Try [Search File Attachments](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_file_attachments) module.